# How to use UINavigationController outside the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, splash-screen

in my current app i´m using a UINavigationController to display the contents of other viewControllers. Its installed within the appDelegate like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];    
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

What i want now is creating a new view controller that displays an intro video right after the splash screen. When the video playback has completed, i want to push my "StartViewController" and install the UINavigationController on it. So that would mean i would setup within one of my others ViewControllers, right?

Is that possible?  Any help on that?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your fast reply. I´ve also just found an interesting blogpost about splash screens:

http://lucas.tiz.ma/blog/2011/09/26/ios-splash-screens-done-right/

For me, that way works. And it seems, it a nice flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like i do below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
    capturedImg = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    self.splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splash];
    [self performSelector:@selector(Load_FirstView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and the Load_FirstView method

```
-(void)Load_FirstView
{    
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

if you want to show video just put one other method and place it between this two methods ie call it first and then from it call Load_firstView method